# Is this a taweez?

Tags: tawiz

I found this in my house I have no idea of what it is and from where it comes from
Any idea ?

Thnx [image]

Comment: Yes! This is a taweez.

Comment: Oh ok thnx and do you know if i should just put it in the bin ?

Comment: Ask your local, trusted mufti /elder on how to dispose this taweez.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a necklace with Imam's name.

If you are familiar with [the Abjad language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad), in this language every letter has a numerical equivalent and after that, every word becomes a number.
In some cases (to preserve the respect of names) instead of names or words, they use the equivalent Abjad number.
I think these are the names of [the Infallibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles).

I know that 92 is used instead of the name of the Prophet and 110 is used instead of the name of Imam Ali, but I did not recognize the rest.

[image]
this is [image]

۹۲ = 92

and

[image] is ۱۱۰ = 110